# Get path of associated file when opened on double click Electron builder

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

Information:

- OS: windows 10
- Electron Version: Latest
- Electron Builder Version: Latest

I am trying to make an app that edits `.txt` files. I want to get the path of the text file when it is opened with the application (i.e. the user chooses to open the `.txt` with my app). I have included the following in the `build` of my `package.json`:

```
"fileAssociations": [
    {
        "name": "Text Files",
        "description": "Plain Text File",
        "ext": [
            "txt"
        ]
    }
],
```

This makes the application open with the file however how do I get the path of the file that was used to open the app. I know I have to do something with a `process.argv` however I have no idea how to use this. I have tried the below with no success:

```js
ipcMain.on('get-file-data', function(event) {
    var data = null;
    if (process.platform == 'win32' && process.argv.length >= 2) {
        var openFilePath = process.argv[1];
        console.log(data)
        win.webContents.send('openFile', openFilePath)
    }
});
```

How can I get the path of the file?

Comment: "Version latest" is not a piece of great information, this question will still be here on this website (hopefully) years later after answered, and saying the latest is not a great idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the path with the following:

```js
const { remote } = require('electron');

console.log(remote.process.argv[1])
```

This returns the path of the file used to open the app!

Comment: I tried your solution, and I thank you. After using process in my code I got some problem so it was solved by using only process without importing from electron.remote.

Answer (score 3):

This is the log of the whole `process`. As we can see here, the second argv is the path of the input file path. So `process.argv[1]` will be enough to the file path. Not sure why you can't get a path.

Maybe this comes from your ipc event listener. Which means the `get-file-data` is not fired correctly.

As you can see in this below image,I'm showing this process variable in this browser console. Here is how I exposed `process` variable to the renderer. But this is just for debug! Recommend not doing this in your production.

`preload.js`

```
process.once("loaded", () => {
    window.process = process;
});
```

`main.js`

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1024,
    height: 728,
    minWidth: 800,
    minHeight: 750,
    webPreferences: {
        enableRemoteModule: true,
        preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    }
});
```

And you can use `window.process` or `process` on your renderer

[image]

Comment: Can you show a code snippet please? I find this very confusing

Comment: @AlexHawking What makes you are confused? I just expose this `process` variable to the renderer and just logged this

Comment: Can you explain how you got the process variable? Was it the same as my code? (sorry if this is a stupid question)

Comment: Thanks for the example... this is what happens when I run `console.log(window.process.argv[1])`: I get the following `--type=renderer`

Comment: Hmm, in this case, try to log whole `process`

Comment: Seems you are adding extra parameters while launching your application.

Comment: Hmm would it help if I gave you a link to my actual source code?